# Dynamic rights for a folder

Tags: debian, permissions, ftp, vsftpd, sharing

So here's the thing. I run debian 10 with VMbox on win10. Kinda getting used to UNIX environment. I use vsftpd to transfer files between virtual Debian and my actual WWin10. I mostly do stuff under root, but I have alex user for my FTP transfers. What I want to do:
I have a folder /home/alex/STUFFMAGREGA where I store files that I want to transfer to my Win10 but the things is that when I copy some logs from /var/log to that folder under root, I can't access them as alex through FTP because I don't have the right permissions.

How do I make it so that when any file ends up in /home/alex/STUFFMAGREGA, it becomes alex's?

Things I've tried:

1. Tried making a group which includes both root and alex with equal permissions to the directory.

   ```
    sudo mkdir -p /home/alex/STUFFMAGREGA 
    sudo groupadd share
    sudo usermod -a -G share alex
    sudo usermod -a -G share root
    sudo chgrp -R share /home/alex/STUFFMAGREGA 
    sudo chmod -R 2775 /home/alex/STUFFMAGREGA
   ```

   It didn't work. I copied a log from /var/log to /home/alex/STUFFMAGREGA under Root and then accessed this ftp folder as Alex, I couldn't open the file. I could only delete it.
2. `chmod g+s alex /home/alex/STUFFMAGREGA`
   or
   `chmod g+s /home/alex/STUFFMAGREGA`.

   Here I tried to make all new files in this directory to inherit the folder's set permissions.

   Didn't work.

Any ideas on how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chmod g+s` will only make new files inherit the "group ownership", but not actually the group *permissions* – those are still decided from the umask. It doesn't get even close to the ACL inheritance that Windows has.

---

However, Linux *does* have a form of ACLs that support inheritance, accessible using the `setfacl` tool. A folder can two kinds of ACL entries, "normal" (affecting the directory itself) and "default" (to be inherited by new files and subfolders).

You can do it in two ways. Either you can continue using g+s for group inheritance and only use ACLs to force files to inherit default-group permissions:

```
chown :share $dir
chmod g+s $dir
setfacl -d -m "group::rwX" $dir
```

Or you can drop g+s and specify an ACL entry that directly grants access to a specific group (both as an 'effective' entry and as an 'inheritable' entry):

```
setfacl -R -m "group:share:rwX" $dir                # Sets the effective ACL.
setfacl -R -d -m "group:share:rwX" $dir             # Sets the inheritable ACL.
```

Shorthand (`g:` for group, `d:` for default/inheritable):

```
setfacl -R -m "g:share:rwX,d:g:share:rwX" $dir
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the second option has worked. Now I finally can copy stuff without any further hindrance.

Comment: I just noticed that I can't edit a file as Alex. I can copy it alright but when I try to edit it in the ftp folder it gives a permission denied error but still I got what I needed. I a, just curious as to why while having all the permissions I still can't edit a file.

Comment: Do you have the permissions both to the file and to the parent directory?

Comment: I can see that my permissions as alex are restricted to read only even though I entered the acl configurations as you told me. That's odd. And the folder in which i work belongs to root:adm. Isn't is supposed to be root:share?